# How to find the visible pushViewController from the navigation controller?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swift4

My app layout consists of a tabbar, from each tab there is a navbar to which is attaches a UITableViewController.

When I didSelect a row, I push a view controller with becomes nicely embedded in the navigation bar.

I would like to find this latter view controller programmatically.

Here is how I push my visible view controller (streamlined version):

```
    @objc
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let vc = WebPageViewController()

        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }
```

I did not managed to find a way. I am using this extension:

```
public extension UIWindow {
    public var visibleViewController: UIViewController? {
        return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(rootViewController)
    }

    public static func getVisibleViewControllerFrom(_ vc: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nc = vc as? UINavigationController {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(nc.visibleViewController)
        } else if let tc = vc as? UITabBarController {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(tc.selectedViewController)
        } else {
            if let pvc = vc?.presentedViewController {
                return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(pvc)
            }
            else if let pushed = vc?.childViewControllers.last {
                return pushed
            }
            else {
                return vc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to find controller below your current controller in navigation stack?

Comment: I want to find WebPageViewController instance I pushed to the navigation controller

Comment: Answer depends on place where you need access WebPageViewController. If you want to find in somewhere in the same navigation controller it will look probably like this:  `        if let viewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first(where: { $0.isKind(of: SPBaseViewController.self) }) as? SPBaseViewController {
            
        }` but it only works if you have only one controller of that type in navigation stack.

Comment: I just don't get why you have the line `UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(nc.visibleViewController)` for `UINavigationController`. If you just pushed your controller, `nc.visibleViewController`is the one you want to have, so it's not necessary to call your extension's function again. If this controller has children controllers, you'll get the children instead of the one you want to have.